# Authentication issues

Tags: php, podio

I have been using the API with no problems for a long time. All of a sudden I'm getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PodioError 
Request URL:

Stack Trace: 
#0 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/vendor/podio/lib/Podio.php(93): Podio::request('POST', '/oauth/token', Array, Array) 
#1 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/pages/careers.php(97): Podio::authenticate('app', Array) 
#2 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/index.php(58): include('/srv/users/serv...') 
#3 {main} 
thrown in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/vendor/podio/lib/Podio.php on line 283
```

I didn't make any changes in my code, or applications key.

The error occurs in this code fragment:

```
<?php 

    require_once 'vendor/podio/PodioAPI.php'; 
    require_once 'vendor/podio/utils/config-careers.php'; 
    Podio::setup(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET); 
    if (!Podio::is_authenticated()) { 
    Podio::authenticate('app', array('app_id' => APP_ID, 'app_token' => APP_TOKEN)); 

}
```

I already made a restart to the server.

Comment: Podio may have changed. Maybe the API had an update?

Comment: Try catching PodioError, and see what the message is. I'm guessing they updated their API.

Comment: Here is the error: PodioError
Request URL: 

Stack Trace: 
#0 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/vendor/podio/lib/Podio.php(93): Podio::request('POST', '/oauth/token', Array, Array)
#1 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/vendor/podio/lib/Podio.php(46): Podio::authenticate('app', Array)
#2 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/pages/careers_tst.php(12): Podio::authenticate_with_app('16704146', '1c527c3f06534d9...')
#3 /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/dellentconsulting/public/index.php(75): include('/srv/users/serv...')
#4 {main}

Comment: The last API update is from Sep 30, 2015.

Comment: I already tried to run this [example](https://developers.podio.com/authentication/app_auth) without success. Can anybody make a simple test?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using? Also, do you have the latest commits for the Podio PHP library?

Comment: Could you please include the full error in addition to the stack trace? That might shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Also please include any request IDs.

Comment: And please be sure to verify that your Client ID and Secret is still correct.

Comment: Without doing nothing the problem was solved. Like I said before this ins't the first time the problem occurs. The last time was a year ago. The system is used on a daily basis.

Comment: The problem is occurring again! Nothing change in our code or server system!

Comment: I believe you have a support ticket open about this and will reach out to them to get more information.

Answer (score -1):

Bit of a wild guess, but could it be a network issue, did you check that you can reach Podio API from the server all the time?